# DriveItem.Size = 0 after upload a file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm uploading lot of files to OneDrive using Graph API. Sometimes I receive DriveItem with size of 0. Response always return 20x status code. When I check file on OneDrive, file size is not displayed at all.

I'm using request for small size files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Are you using any of the client SDKs?

Comment: Yes. I use .NET Client

Comment: What is the sizes of the file you plan on uploading? Are they large files greater than 5MB?

Comment: It's about 1KB.